# The term 'Get-AzStorageAccount' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops

I try to run some AZ powershell comands from DevOps pipeline on self-hosted agent which is connected to the machine 'myMachine'.
So the error comes from the line where I use Get-AzStorageAccount. Below is the script.
`$context = (Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName "myResource" -Name "myResourceStorage").Context`
The complete error message is: "**The term 'Get-AzStorageAccount' is not recognized as the name of
a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again**"
The strange issue is that, if I execute the script manually from the machine, it works without problems.
So, the error comes by executing it from devops pipeline. As it is self-hosted agent, what it does is it copies ps1 script from devops repository to the myMachine and runs it from there. So logically there is no difference by running it manually or from pipeline.

Latest AZ module is installed at C:\Users\myAdminUser\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules

I tried to put "Import-Module -Name Az" or just "Import-Module -Name Az.Accounts".
This also works fine by running it manually. But from pipeline I get error "**The specified module 'Az.Accounts' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module
directory**"

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Tried running it manually as indicated in the question description. Running the ps1 manually from the machine works, but not from the devops pipeline with the "Powershell" task

Comment: having the same issue.  have u resolved this?